# Does anyone have any advice on how to build a reverse proxy in php without a third party service?

Tags: php, reverse-proxy

For a university project I have created a web-based application, a student grade checker, each function has a different port, as part of the project I've been asked to create a reverse proxy, without any third party services ideally in php as the containers are all written in php. I've spent the last few days googling it and can't find a single step by step guide or tutorial on how to build one, in theory it seems relatively easy but I can't figure it out.

Effectively I just want to create a reverse proxy server that links to each function of the app when selected, any help at all would be greatly appreciated, even a push in the right direction to a video or step by step guide.

Comment: "each function has a different port" bizarre choice.  Put them all on the same server and use paths to distinguish functions, not ports, and that obviates a reverse proxy.

Comment: so each function is a different container, when i build run the container I have to assign a port, later down the line I will be deploying them through rancher so it won't be the same as localhost different ports, but I have to create a reverse proxy as part of the assignment otherwise I wouldn't

Comment: "without any third party services ideally in php as the containers are all written in php".  How are you running your PHP apps now - are they under apache/php-fpm?  You say "without third party services".   What about an open source reverse proxy?  You can do that thing with Apache for example, HAProxy, Nginx

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic fetching of an url and output it directly to the browser.
You can work from here and add a switch case to define the remote url so you will endup with a single endpoint.

```php
// the base url / port you want to proxy
$remoteUrl = 'https://localhost:443';

// append the current request URI to the remote URL
$remoteUrl .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// return the output fetched from the remote URL
if( $stream = fopen( $remoteUrl, 'rb' ) ) {
    echo stream_get_contents( $stream, );
    fclose( $stream );
} else {
    echo sprintf( 'Error reading url: %s', $remoteUrl );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is effectively what I need, I am useless at php, so in your example is rb what I would put the container name or how would I enable it to reroute to the desired port? I know this is very basic, but my head is fried from looking at this for days and I can't figure it out so I appreciate any help

Comment: you can put the container host/port in $remoteUrl. In my example 443 is the port. 'rb' is a param for 'fopen' (rb - read binary) to make it binary safe.